# Does Core Data/SQLite compress redundant information?

Tags: cocoa, sqlite, core-data

I want to use Core Data (probably with SQLite backing) to store a large database.  *Much* of the string data will be the same between numerous rows.  Does Core Data/SQLite see such redundancy, and automatically save space in the db files?

Do I need to make sure that the same text in different rows is the same string *object* before adding it to the db?  If so, how do I detect that a new piece of text matches something *anywhere* in the existing db?

Answer (score 1):

No, Core Data does not attempt to analyze your data to avoid duplication. If you want to save 10 million objects with the same attributes, you'll get 10 million copies.

If you want to avoid creating duplicate instances, you need to do a fetch for matching instances before creating a new one. The general approach is

1. Fetch objects matching new data-- according to whatever standard indicates a duplicate for your app. Use a predicate with the fetch that contains the attribute(s) that you don't want to duplicate.
2. If you find anything, either (a) update the instances you find with any new values you have, or (b) if there are no new values, do nothing.
3. If you *don't* find anything, create a new instance.

Comment: It's not a matter of entire records being duplicates or needing updated.  This application is analyzing save-game files from a complex game.  My db will contain (among other things) 10s of thousands of people.  Each will have attributes, including first names, birthdates, religion, etc.  Due to the nature of the game, there will be many of people sharing first names, and a *lot* of people with the same religion.  I expect I'll need to turn the text of the religion into an ID referencing a separate religion table, but I'm not sure whether that's worth doing for first names.

Comment: The only way to reuse strings across multiple instances is to factor them out into a new entity type. That might make sense for a "religion" field, but probably won't for a first name field.

Comment: For what it's worth, I expect on the order of 100,000 to 150,000 unique persons, sharing 14,000 to 15,000 unique names.  That's an average of 6-10 people per name, with a few names shared by 100+ people each.

Answer (score 0):

Application-layer logic can help reduce space at the cost of application complexity.

Say your name field can contain either an integer or a string. (SQLite's weak typing makes this easy to do).

If string -- that's the name right there.

If integer -- go look it up on a name table, using the int as key

Of course you have to create that name table, either on the fly as data is inserted, or a once-in-a-while trawl through the data for new names that are worth surrogating in this way.